# IIS reverse proxy bypass 2gb upload limit

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, windows-server-2016

I have an IIS 10 reverse proxy to a tomcat app which requires larger than 2gb file uploads. Is there a way I can bypass the system.web/httpRuntime.maxRequestLength 2gb max to at least get to the 4gb limit set by request filtering?

Setup:

- Windows Server 2016
- IIS 10
- ARR 3.0
- URL Rewrite 2.1
- 8gb Memory